# Windows Phone XNA and Silverlight Cannot use Pivot Control?

Tags: silverlight, xna, windows-phone, pivot

I'm trying to create a Windows Phone 7 combo application that uses Silverlight + XNA ("Windows Phone XAML and XNA" template). One page will have XNA+Silverlight UI controls and the rest will be pure UI pages with no XNA. I'd like to use the Pivot control on one of the pure UI pages, but it keeps throwing errors when I add the default Pivot page template.

The specified value cannot be assinged to the collection. The following type was expected: "UIElement"

Cannot add content to an object of type "Pivot"
...

I can't seem to find any information why Pivot controls would not be allowed. Anyone have any insight into why using Pivots are not working with XNA+Silverlight? Especially since its being used on a UI only page (no XNA). The Pivot page is fine if I create a Silverlight only project. This is on Visual Studio 2012 btw. Thanks!